# Datatype for 1 character only

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert only one letter into the table field. What will be the data type that will accept only one character?

I don't want to use `VARCHAR(1)`, because it will truncate the remaining characters. I want that if the input is 1 character, it will insert otherwise it will not insert into the table

Comment: What about `CHAR(1)`?

Comment: data is inserting... but truncating if we give string of more than one character :(

Comment: Need to check that prior to the insert really. Although you could use a (say) VARCHAR(255) and use a trigger to check the length on INSERT / UPDATE (and force a failure in that case).

Comment: You're using PHP (mysqli), so you obviously need to let PHP check the strlen(). Giving this task to MySQL is not a good idea because logic belongs to the scripting language and data-processing to the database. Try to think broader than the scope of one language in a project if you're using multiple.

Comment: MySQL _will_ truncate the value, unless you have strict mode enabled. If you don’t want an insert to happen if the string is more than one character, then this is a business rule and something you should be checking in your application, not letting the database handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the column length to be longer (for example, 255), then you can add a trigger which checks the length of the new field. If greater than 1 then you can trigger an error.

For a test example:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insert_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sometext` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


--
-- Triggers `insert_test`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `length_check_trigger`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `length_check_trigger` BEFORE INSERT ON `insert_test`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
    IF LENGTH(NEW.sometext) > 1 THEN
        SET msg = "DIE: String Too Long.";
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
    END IF;

END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

You can change the message to what you want. You will need a similar trigger to catch updates as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the datatype:

```
TINYTEXT
```

?
 or would it not work on the system you are using?

Comment: data is inserting... but truncating if we give string of more than one character :(

Comment: If it was an integer it would be easy, but I don't currently know. I'll get back to you if I find it.

Answer (score 2):

In mysql the data type itself does not control if the attempt to insert / update a field to a longer (invalid) data, than it is allowed by the field definition results in an error or warning.

In mysql you need to set the sql mode to one of the strict sql modes as described by mysql's documentation on [sql mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html).

> If strict mode is not in effect, MySQL inserts adjusted values for
> invalid or missing values and produces warnings (see Section
> 13.7.5.40, “SHOW WARNINGS Syntax”). In strict mode, you can produce this behavior by using INSERT IGNORE or UPDATE IGNORE.

So, both varchar(1) and char(1) are correct definitions, however, you need to enable strict sql mode in order for inserting / updating invalid data to produce an error. Setting sql mode in config file or using set statement is described in the linked documentation:

> To set the SQL mode at server startup, use the --sql-mode="modes"
> option on the command line, or sql-mode="modes" in an option file such
> as my.cnf (Unix operating systems) or my.ini (Windows). modes is a
> list of different modes separated by commas. To clear the SQL mode
> explicitly, set it to an empty string using --sql-mode="" on the
> command line, or sql-mode="" in an option file.  ...  To change the
> SQL mode at runtime, set the global or session sql_mode system
> variable using a SET statement:
>
> `SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes'`;
>
> `SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes'`;